# Symfony expecting an ArrayCollection for a single-entity attribute

Tags: object, collections, doctrine, transform

I have entity called "Post":

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserSubscriptionTier", inversedBy="posts")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 */
private $subscriptionTier;

... and all the various get/set functions 

}
```

So my main point here is that the $subscriptionTier is not a collection object, but merely a single-entity attribute.

Here is what the form type class looks like:

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var UserProvider
     */
    protected $userProvider;

```
public function __construct(UserProvider $userProvider)
{
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'File or Files',
            'required' => false,
            'mapped'   => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')
        ])
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('subscriptionTier', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => UserSubscriptionTier::class,
            'choices'  => $this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()->getSubscriptionTiers(),
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'save')
        ))
    ;
}
```

So the subscriptionTier is simply a single entity attribute, with a bunch of options to select from.

Here is what it looks like when I build it out in twig, from the incoming form:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="subscriptions" required="required">
    <option disabled selected>Visibility</option>
        {% for key,val in postForm.subscriptionTier.vars.choices %}
            {% if val.data.tierNumber == 1 %}
            <option value="{{ val.value }}" {{  postForm.subscriptionTier.vars.value == '' and key == 0 ? ' selected ' :(val.value == postForm.subscriptionTier.vars.value ? ' selected ' : '') }}>All Subscribers</option>
            {% endif %}
            <option value="{{ val.value }}" {{ postForm.subscriptionTier.vars.value == '' and key == 0 ? ' selected ' :(val.value == postForm.subscriptionTier.vars.value ? ' selected ' : '') }}>{{ val.label | trans }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here is the controller code after the form is submitted:

```
public function createPostAction(PostRepository $postRepository, Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $subscriptionId = $request->request->get('subscriptions');
        $userSubscriptionTier = $this->subscriptionTierRepository->find($subscriptionId);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->setUser($user);
        $post->setSubscriptionTier($userSubscriptionTier);
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
```

It is this createForm function which triggers the following error:

```
Unable to transform value for property path "subscriptionTier": Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.
```

Why is Symfony expecting a collections object for a single entity attribute?  Did the multi-option choice in the form trick Symfony into expecting an ArrayCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but isn't it because of the `'multiple' => true` here:

```
->add('subscriptionTier', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => UserSubscriptionTier::class,
        'choices'  => $this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()->getSubscriptionTiers(),
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'required' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    ])
```

I think it creates mutli-value select, which is expected to pass a collection with multiple values.

Here's what the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) say about this field:

> multiple
>   type: boolean default: false
>
> If true, the user will be able to select multiple options (as opposed to choosing just one option). Depending on the value of the expanded option, this will render either a select tag or checkboxes if true and a select tag or radio buttons if false. The returned value will be an array.

Strange thing is your twig output doesn't contain a select with "multiple" on it, so I'm a bit confused, but it's worth a try.